# mongo addShard "No common protocol found" errmsg 126

Tags: mongodb, docker, virtual-machine, sharding

I'm trying to learn some MongoDB and want to mount a two sharded DB for distributing my data between these two "nodes" and take advantage of its efficiency and robustness.

I'm also working over [Docker](https://www.docker.com/what-docker). So in docker I created 4 VMs with their respective IPs:

- mongo1(172.17.0.6): first db to use as shard
- mongo2(172.17.0.5): second db to use as shard
- mongocfg(172.17.0.4): a config image for the whole system
- mongorouter(172.17.0.3): the router to access both other shards; the whole db

If you're not familiarized with docker just think of it like a VirtualBox manager who helps running multiple virtual images under the same environment and OS. For instance, just think every IPs up there are just different computers.

The thing is that to add a new shard, I've read that I need to connect to mongorouter and then add both shards by their IP and port. In docker, I execute `$ docker exec -it mongorouter mongo` and the mongo console appears as

`mongos>`

and there I type and get exactly:

`mongos> sh.addShard("172.17.0.6:27017")
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "No common protocol found.", "code" : 126 }`

And I've tried to look what does that mean and haven't got any clue. It's not just simple googling as I thought myself. Of course the shard is not added after this. In a deseperate shot I've tried all of the IPs, even with the Gateway for all of them `172.17.0.2`.

I could use some advice just with the correct documentation like where to find the error code 126 or what protocol is the errmsg referring or anything.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT.

I didn't found the solution. The problem was because I was using an incorrect Dockerfile to build the VM. If anyone is interested, the difference was that the wrong Docker file had a `FROM ubuntu:latest` and the correct one had `FROM mongo`. If someone get here with the same problem, that's the better direction I could point you.

Comment: Can you ping docker instance running on 172.17.* ips? Also verify if desired ports are opened and properly mapped.

Comment: I can't ping them. But a friend doing the same procedure, is able to add the shard and doesn't ping any ip either. 
And they seem to be properly mapped as the Network Settings say "Ports": {"27017/tcp": [{"HostIp": "0.0.0.0","HostPort": "27030"}]}. If I try to add the Shard with 27030, I only get connection refused

Comment: well, you need to contact with your friend and make sure you are following all necessary steps.